# Retrieving data from Windows environment with Rosbridge

Tags: ubuntu, rosbridge, windows, ros-noetic

By activating Rosbridge from the Ubuntu environment, I can send target location information to the robot via Windows. Is it possible to receive the sent command information from the Ubuntu environment via Rosbridge?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on the same network, you can access topics on another device regardless of the platform.

Take a look at this link: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines